# Error occurs in Spring 4.2.0

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I have the following in my pom.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
          xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
        <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
        <groupId>app.pdf</groupId>
        <artifactId>pdf</artifactId>
        <name>PdfGen</name>
        <packaging>war</packaging>
        <version>0.1</version>
        <properties>
          <java-version>1.6</java-version>
          <org.springframework-version>4.2.0.RELEASE</org.springframework-version>
          <org.aspectj-version>1.7.4</org.aspectj-version>
          <org.slf4j-version>1.6.6</org.slf4j-version>
        </properties>
        <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <!-- Exclude Commons Logging in favor of SLF4j -->
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                 </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${org.springframework-version}</version>
          </dependency>

          <!-- AspectJ -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjrt</artifactId>
            <version>${org.aspectj-version}</version>
          </dependency> 

          <!-- Logging -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>${org.slf4j-version}</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
                    <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
          </dependency>

          <!-- @Inject -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.inject</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.inject</artifactId>
            <version>1</version>
          </dependency>

          <!-- Servlet -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.1</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
          </dependency>
          <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
          </dependency>

          <!-- Test -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.7</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
          </dependency>  

          <!-- JSON -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>net.minidev</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-smart</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.9</version>
          </dependency>   

          <!-- iTextPDF -->
          <dependency>
            <groupId>com.itextpdf</groupId>
            <artifactId>itextpdf</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.6</version>
          </dependency>   
      </dependencies>
      <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.9</version>
                <configuration>
                <additionalProjectnatures>
                      <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                      </additionalProjectnatures>
                      <additionalBuildcommands>
                      <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
                      </additionalBuildcommands>
                      <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                      <downloadJavadocs>true</downloadJavadocs>
                  </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.6</source>
                    <target>1.6</target>
                    <compilerArgument>-Xlint:all</compilerArgument>
                    <showWarnings>true</showWarnings>
                    <showDeprecation>true</showDeprecation>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <mainClass>org.test.int1.Main</mainClass>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
        <pluginManagement>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.7</version>
            </plugin>           
          </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>   
    </build>
</project>
```

This gives me the following errors in servlet-context.xml:

Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.config.AnnotationDrivenBeanDefinitionParser
 $CompositeUriComponentsContributorFactoryBean' not found [config set: PdfGen/web-context]

for

```
 <annotation-driven />
```

and

Multiple annotations found at this line:
    - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver' not found
    - Class 'org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver' not found [config set: PdfGen/web-
     context]

for

```
  <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
     <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
     <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
  </beans:bean>
```

Can anybody please help me with this?

Comment: Did you try adding `<context:annotation-config />` in your context.xml? It will  register preregistered beans in spring context.

Comment: You try remove spring context lib from pom.xml